# Some problems no longer generate console messages, but are surfaced in the issues tab. Click to view page 1 error

Tags: javascript, electron

My console showed this message today. In my console, no error is described, but i still see that red flag, why?
Im using electron, electron client, and gulp [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you have filtered the chrome console. Click on the console sidebar & change the filter

[image: Chrome console filters]